# Pandas: How to match / filter same key / id values (duplicates) from 2 different dataframes and replace values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, dataset

I have 2 dataframes of different sizes. The first dataframe(`df1`) has 4 columns, but two of those columns have the same name as the columns in the second dataframe(`df2`), which is only comprised of 2 columns. The columns in common are `['ID']` and `['Department']`.

I want to check if any `ID` from `df2` are in `df1`. If so, I want to replace `df1['Department']` value with `df2['Department']` value.

For instance, `df1` looks something like this:

```
ID      Department     Yrs Experience      Education
1234    Science        1                   Bachelors
2356    Art            3                   Bachelors
2456    Math           2                   Masters
4657    Science        4                   Masters
```

And `df2` looks something like this:

```
ID      Department    
1098    P.E.
1234    Technology       
2356    History
```

I want to check if the `ID` from `df2` is in `df1` and if so, update `Department`. The output should looks something like this:

```
ID      Department     Yrs Experience      Education
1234    **Technology** 1                   Bachelors
2356    **History**    3                   Bachelors
2456    Math           2                   Masters
4657    Science        4                   Masters
```

The expected updates to `df1` are in bold

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Thank you for taking the time to read this and help.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input dataframes `df1`, `df2` and expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I just edited it

Comment: Edited question to improve sample data of `df2` to more realistic data where the matching items row indexes are not necessarily the same as `df1` indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ID` of `df1` to map with the Pandas series formed by setting `ID` on `df2` as index and taking the column of `Department` from `df2` (this acts as a mapping table).

Then, in case of no match of `ID` from `df2`, we fill-in the original values of `Department` from `df1` (to retain original values in case of no match):

```
df1['Department'] = (df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['Department'])
                              .fillna(df1['Department'])
                    )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

     ID  Department  Yrs Experience  Education
0  1234  Technology               1  Bachelors
1  2356     History               3  Bachelors
2  2456        Math               2    Masters
3  4657     Science               4    Masters
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[1234, 2356, 2456, 4657], 'Department':['Science', 'Art', 'Math', 'Science']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[1234, 2356], 'Department':['Technology', 'History']})

df_1.loc[df_1['ID'].isin(df_2['ID']), 'Department'] = df_2['Department']
```

OutPut

```
     ID  Department
0  1234  Technology
1  2356     History
2  2456        Math
3  4657     Science
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I tried your solution. It partially works. It correctly identifies the IDs from df2 in df1, but it doesn't replace the Department. Instead, it outputs blank. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I tried on your dataframes and it worked fine.

Comment: Check the output. this is what i got.

Comment: The real data is that the row indexes of matching `ID` rows are different from the 2 dataframes.  Hence, your solution assigning directly from one dataframe to another (and this requires same indexes of matching items) would give incorrect result.  Try with the modified `df2` with one more row at the first row, then you will see what this mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df1["Department"].update(
    df1[["ID"]].merge(df2, on="ID", how="left")["Department"]
)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
     ID  Department  Yrs Experience  Education
0  1234  Technology               1  Bachelors
1  2356     History               3  Bachelors
2  2456        Math               2    Masters
3  4657     Science               4    Masters
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I tried your solution and unfortunately, it's not updating df1

Comment: @shorttriptomars Look at result of `df1[["ID"]].merge(df2, on="ID", how="left")` and check if `df1` and `df2` have merged correctly.

Comment: I checked and they are not merging correctly. I even changed how to "right" but that didn't work either

Comment: @shorttriptomars Make sure the `ID` columns are of the same type. If it's string, check any whitespaces in it.

Comment: For both `ID` columns, the type is `int64`. While the type for both `Department` was `object`, I converted both to `str` just to make sure. Now when merged, it outputs a blank in `df1` instead of the value from `df2`